# Работа с событиями JavaScript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Доброго времени суток

Вот не как не могу сообразить как правильно организовать код, а именно для работы с событиями

Есть обычный блок

```
<div id="content">
      тут разные теги
</div>
```

В этот блок периодически добавляется/заменяется html код

Грубо говоря, это можно сказать что-то типа сайта который работает без обновления страницы, соответственно js код загружается только один раз при первом заходе на сайт

Вообщем суть проблемы
Допустим в этот блок id="content" добавились сообщения "чат"

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="wrapChat">
        <div class="message">
            <span class="remove">Удалить</span>
            Тут сообщение
        </div>
        <div class="messgae">
            <span class="remove">Удалить</span>
            Тут сообщение
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Либо там товары

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="item">
        Тут товар 1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Тут товар 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос как правильно вешать события на динамический контент?

Конечно же первое о чем подумал это "делегирование событий" но тут есть одно большое НО

В блок подгружается много разного контента, это получается на каждую кнопочку нужно вешать событие через id="content" типа:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var content = $("#content");

        content.on("click", "#wrapChat .remove", function (e) {
            // тут чо-то важное
        });

        content.on("mouseenter", "#wrapChat .message", function (e) {
            // тут чо-то важное
        });

        content.on("click", ".item", function (e) {
            // тут чо-то важное
        });

        // ...
        // ...
        // ...
        // ...
        // ...
        // ...
});
```

А что если форум подгружать там удаление сообщений, добавление, цитировать, ответить, вообщем разных кнопок много на которые нужно вещать события

Мне кажется это как-то не правильно, или мне это кажется? )

Буду благодарен за любую помощь )

Для меня это все в диковинку так как я больше по серверной части "гуляю"

P.S Из за своих "тараканов" я не могу повесить событие на прямую в html типа

```
<div class="item" onclick="">
```

Comment: присылайте скрипт с событиями (делегирование продолжайте использовать) как часть динамического контента. В скриптах, добавляющих обработчики событий, проверяйте были ли они уже добавлены.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Событие можно вешать на класс или произвольный селектор, например:

```
$('.contact-addr a').click(function(event) {
  ....
});
```

Для динамических элементов click() не работает, для них надо делать так:

```
$('.portfolio_filter').each(function(){
  var $this_filter = $(this);
  $this_filter.on('click', 'a', function(){
    ....
  });
});
```

Comment: Динамический контент, jquery о новом html не будет попросту знать, html который подгружен скажем через ajax

Comment: Ерунда полная. Как раз будет. Как раз так и делал через .on() для контента (галереи), подгружаемой через ajax.

Comment: вот этот кусок с portfolio-filter я выдернул со своего сайта, где ajax

Comment: Я так и написал
        var content = $("#content");

        content.on("click", "#wrapChat .remove", function (e) {
            // тут чо-то важное
        });
Но таких обработчиков нужно сразу тогда кучу писать так как js у меня загружается только один раз при первом заходе на сайт, получается когда событие будет "всплывать" оно будет сверятся с этой кучей обработчиков

Comment: а первое предложение прочитать? ))) Вешать можно на КЛАСС. Один обработчик на 100500 элементов сразу.

Comment: Грубо говоря у меня сайт состоит всего из одного блока <div id="content"> собственно который я и могу средствами jquery инициализировать в момент загрузки страницы, а все остальное уже динамическое

Comment: ну и что? вешайте на КЛАСС типа `.my-button`, при добавлении в DOM новых элементов с классом `.my-button` браузер добавит им EventListener

Comment: Если вешать события на новый html они будут дублироваться при каждой подгрузке одного контента скажем чата
Получается нужно будет офать события после смены контента типа 
content.off("mouseenter", "#wrapChat .message");
Либо удалять весь блок через .remove чего я не могу делать )

Comment: да вы попробуйте, к чему эти теории. не было у вас кнопок при загрузке - ок. загрузили еще 5 кнопок, на них подвесились события. еще 125 загрузили - и на них автоматом подвесились. чего там оффать? Говорю вам, все работает.

Comment: lol я был уверен что $(селектор).html(new); просто заменяет html на новый, это все русская документация в которой упускают половину важнейшей информации, зашел на оф сайт, а там так и написано
jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content.
То есть jquere удаляет все обработчики до вставки нового html
А я то думал что это делает только .remove и .empty
Тупо потратил 2 дня на поиски правильно архитектуры кода )
Спасибо вам за подсказку )

Comment: ну если ответ помог, то можно его и отметить как-то. Непонятно, правда, по каким критериям вы приняли другой ответ, в то в время как я ответил первым, с примером кода и длинными комментариями

Comment: Извиняюсь ошибочка вышла, промахнулся )

Comment: Спасибо за понимание

Answer (score 0):

Данный метод подходит для динамически появляющихся элементов с классом "mySelector"

```
$(document).on('click', '.mySelector', function(e) {
  // обработка события
})
```

Answer (score 0):

класс ДинКонтент  - все что подгружается на страницу, 
на любой тег ставите проперти какое то - фото , док , чат и дт и тп .
так же добавляете id тегу  - для фото это номер фото , для дока - имя дока , для чата  - имя пользователя

получается нажали на класс ДивКонтент , определили проперти , по проперти определили тип контента и как вы его обрабатываете,
по аиди получили именно тот тег , на котором был клик

в результате имеете тип выбранного контента , 
по типу отправляете контент в функцию , работающую с данным видом контента, 
по аиди работаете именно с нужным вам элементом в указанной функции ...